# Pandas to JSON can't get it in the right format

Tags: python, json, pandas

This is really frustrating me and I feel like I've tried everything. I have a basic Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
order   name        lat     long    open    close
123     Walgreens   37.5    50.4    08:00:00    17:00:00
456     CVS         16.7    52.4    09:00:00    12:00:00
789     McDonald's  90.7    59.1    12:00:00    14:00:00
```

I need to convert that dataframe into a JSON object that looks like this:

```
    {
      "123": {
    "Location": {
      "Name": "Walgreens",
      "Lat": 37.5,
      "Long": 50.4
    },
    "Open": 08:00:00,
    "Close": 17:00:00
  },
  "456": {
    "Location": {
      "Name": "CVS",
      "Lat": 16.7,
      "Long": 52.4
    },
    "Open": 09:00:00,
    "Close": 12:00:00
  },
  "789": {
    "Location": {
      "Name": "McDonald's", 
      "Lat": 90.7, 
      "Long":   59.1
     }, 
     "Open": 12:00:00, 
    "Close" : 14:00:00 } } }
```

I have tried quite a few methods trying to get it to look like that, but either I get stuck with extra slashes or I can't get my quotes right no matter what I do. I have done both the Pandas to_json method and made it into a dictionary and then done json.loads or json.dumps and it just won't work right.

One method I tried is doing this:

```
json_dict = {}

    for i in df.index:
        order_no = df.loc[i, 'order_no']
        stop_name = df.loc[i, 'Name']
        lat = df.loc[i, 'latitude']
        lng = df.loc[i, 'longitude']   
        start = df.loc[i, 'start']
        end = df.loc[i, 'end']
        json_dict[str(order_no)] = '{{"location" : {{  "name":  "{0}", 
        "lat" : "{1}", "long" : "{2}" }}, "open" : "{3}", "close" : "{4}"  
         }}'.format(name, lat, long, start, end)

      json.dumps(json_dict)
```

and it ends up throwing in a whole bunch of backslashes in it. How do I get the formatting right? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should be parsing that file using beautifulsoup or lxml, not loading it into a dataframe as html

Comment: @Chris I think the html was just for formatting, I don't think OP is loading the dataframe from html explicitly

Comment: `'{{"location" : {{  "name":  "{0}", 
        "lat" : "{1}", "long" : "{2}" }}, "open" : "{3}", "close" : "{4}"` is a string. It will get serialized to a JSON string. That's why it has backslashes in it, if thats what you mean.

Comment: I think `df.to_json(orient='records')` should work here

Comment: @Chris, yes C.Nivs is right: I am not loading it into a dataframe as html, I just made it html to demo what the table looks like here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with a source dataframe, `df` that looks like:

```
order   name        lat     long    open        close
123     Walgreens   37.5    50.4    08:00:00    17:00:00
456     CVS         16.7    52.4    09:00:00    12:00:00
789     McDonald's  90.7    59.1    12:00:00    14:00:00
```

to get the desired output json, we need to do the following:

- Convert column names to Capitalcase
- Create a `Location` column of type dictionary, aggregating `name`, `lat`, `long`
- Convert to json, where the `order` is the top level key

Code:

```
# import json & pprint to pretty print the output
import json
import pprint

import pandas as pd

df.columns = [x.capitalize() for x in df.columns]
location_keys = ['Name', 'Lat', 'Long']
df['Location'] = df[location_keys].to_dict(orient='records')  
json_str = df.set_index('Order').drop(location_keys, axis=1).to_json(orient='index')

# print output with nice json formatting
pprint.pprint(json.loads(json_str))
# outputs:
{'123': {'Close': '17:00:00',
         'Location': {'Lat': '37.5', 'Long': '50.4', 'Name': 'Walgreens'},
         'Open': '08:00:00'},
 '456': {'Close': '12:00:00',
         'Location': {'Lat': '16.7', 'Long': '52.4', 'Name': 'CVS'},
         'Open': '09:00:00'},
 '789': {'Close': '14:00:00',
         'Location': {'Lat': '90.7', 'Long': '59.1', 'Name': "McDonald's"},
         'Open': '12:00:00'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the index to be `order`, you can then orient on `index`:

```py
import pandas as pd

records
[{'order': '123', 'name': 'Walgreens', 'lat': '37.5', 'long': '50.4', 'open': '08:00:00', 'close': '17:00:00'}, {'order': '456', 'name': 'CVS', 'lat': '16.7', 'long': '52.4', 'open': '09:00:00', 'close': '12:00:00'}, {'order': '789', 'name': "McDonald's", 'lat': '90.7', 'long': '59.1', 'open': '12:00:00', 'close': '14:00:00'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df = df.set_index('order')
```

Now `df` looks like

```
close   lat  long        name      open
order
123    17:00:00  37.5  50.4   Walgreens  08:00:00
456    12:00:00  16.7  52.4         CVS  09:00:00
789    14:00:00  90.7  59.1  McDonald's  12:00:00
```

To get it to a python `dict`

```py
df.to_dict(orient='index')

{
   "123": {
      "close": "17:00:00",
      "lat": "37.5",
      "long": "50.4",
      "name": "Walgreens",
      "open": "08:00:00"
   },
   "456": {
      "close": "12:00:00",
      "lat": "16.7",
      "long": "52.4",
      "name": "CVS",
      "open": "09:00:00"
   },
   "789": {
      "close": "14:00:00",
      "lat": "90.7",
      "long": "59.1",
      "name": "McDonald's",
      "open": "12:00:00"
   }
}
```

So as a complete statement

```py
# if you prefer a one-liner

# as python dict
json_dict = df.set_index('order').to_dict(orient='index')

# or as json string
json_string = df.set_index('order').to_json(orient='index')
```

Answer (score -1):

tl;dr

I had a similar struggle trying to get the right JSON format from the Pandas dataframe that I wanted to use to drive an API. I took a cue from how we normally work with SQL where we parse a problematic date value to string before using a built-in function to convert to date.
...
You could consider doing

`json.dumps(json.loads(data_frame.to_json(orient="records")))`

if it helps